# Android Kotlin RecyclerView and menu item intent pass value to a second activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-adapter

I'm working on a simple task which presents a list using recyclerview

adapter class

```
class MedalAdapter(private val context: Context, private val datalist: MutableList<Medal>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MedalAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MedalAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = layoutInflater
            .inflate(R.layout.medal_layout, parent, false) as View
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = datalist.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MedalAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = datalist[position]
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(val v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        val medal = v.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.medal)
        val name = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.country)
        val abbr = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.abbreviation)
        val number = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.number)

        fun bind(item: Medal) {
            var total = item.gold.toInt() + item.silver.toInt() + item.bronze.toInt()
            name.text = item.name
            abbr.text = item.abbreviation
            number.text = total.toString()
            number.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
            if (item.gold.toInt() > item.silver.toInt() && item.gold.toInt() > item.bronze.toInt()) {
                medal.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
                name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D4AF37"))
                abbr.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
            }
            var toast = name.text as String + " has won " + item.gold + " gold medals"
            v.setOnClickListener{
                Toast.makeText(v.context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("name", item.name)
                intent.putExtra("abbr", item.abbreviation)
                intent.putExtra("medal", item)
                Log.i("Click Event", "name: " + item.name)
                Log.i("Click Event", "medal: " + item)
//                activity.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

mainactivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var medal: Medal
    private val TAG = "MyActivity"


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val medallist = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.medallist)

        val datalist = mutableListOf<Medal>()
        medallist.adapter = MedalAdapter(this, datalist)
        medallist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        resources.openRawResource(R.raw.medallists).bufferedReader()
            .forEachLine {
                val temp = it.split(",")
                val name = temp[0]
                val abbr = temp[1]
                val number = temp[2]
                val gold = temp[3]
                val silver = temp[4]
                val bronze = temp[5]
                medal = Medal(name, abbr, number, gold, silver, bronze)
                datalist.add(medal)
                Log.i(TAG, "" + medal.toString());
            }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "onPause")
        val sharePref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        with (sharePref.edit()) {

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.save, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.save -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
                Log.i("Medal", "name: " + medal.name)
//                intent.putExtra("name", medal.name)
//                intent.putExtra("abbr", medal.abbreviation)
                startActivity(intent)
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

secondactivity

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var medal: Medal? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)
        medal = intent.getParcelableExtra<Medal>("medal")
        val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val abbr = intent.getStringExtra("abbr")
        Log.i("Medal", "medalname: " + name)
        medal?.let {

        }
        val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.result)
        result.text = "The last country clicked was " + name + "(" + abbr + ")"
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "onPause")
        val sharePref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        with (sharePref.edit()) {
            val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.result)
            putString("result", result.text.toString())
            apply()
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
    }
}
```

This app worked as below
[medal list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pcOZ.png)
Each time I clicked on one item in the list, the country name and country code will be stored, but it will not switch to the second activity. Then, when I click the menu item in the menu on the top right side, it will lead to the layout of second activity and show the name and code previously I clicked. I ran my code and found that the second activity always showed the null value. Not sure where I did wrong, could really use some help here. Many thanks.

Comment: When u click on a recycler view item, the view holder prepares an intent and starts DetailActivity. Is this much working?

Comment: The thing is, when the item has been clicked, I want the related details to be store but not start DetailActivity. When I clicked on the menu item under menu, it starts the second activity and shows the stored data.

Comment: And where do you want to store the data? In MainActivity?

Comment: I managed to fix it by passing intent of data from adapter to MainActivity, and get the intent data in MainActivity and pass it to DetailActivity. Many thanks. Since currently the intent of list item data will start MainActivity itself, a second question is that when I click the list item, it will refresh the MainActivity layout, how can I prevent this refreshing action?

Comment: What did you do? Are you restarting the MainActivity when item is clicked?

Comment: It's kinda like this. When the item is clicked, MainActivity will be started

Comment: Instead of restarting the MainActivity, you can pass the item data back to the activity and save it there. Now when user clicks on option menu item, you can take that data and forward it to DetailActivity

Comment: I would store any data in a ViewModel. Otherwise, any configuration change like the screen rotating will reset everything.